# Set the default value to the jmeter local variable same as the property variable

Tags: jmeter

We can set the default value for property variable `${__P(Threads,1)}`, if `Threads` is null then the default value 1 will be used.

Now I want to use the variable in the same way.

We can call the variable as `${name}` in JMeter and if this `name` is null then the default variable should come into action.

I don't want to use preprocessors need in format of function same as property variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest equivalent would be [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V):

```
${__V(name,default value)}
```

Alternatively you can declare the initial values of the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using i.e. [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) configuration element like:

[image]